# A website auto creates pdfs from smaller pdfs randomly

Tags: pdf

I have to create a web page that automatically creates :

A pdf(1-2 pages) from smaller pdfs(1/8 page)

For example user prefers what kind of small pdfs he/she wants from predefined categories , and web site automatically creates another pdf, using small pdfs from the web site, saves it and gives the link of the new pdf.

I want to know how I can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP you can use these libraries

- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Cheers!